# Shell starts in edit only mode. No prompt shows up, no commands can be executed

Tags: linux, shell

My tcsh shows up in a weird manner. Be it as a login shell or in terminal, now it always starts with just a cursor. I can type a text in terminal but that's all about what I can do. No prompt does show up, no binded keys work, ***no commands get executed***, ***control sequences just got echoed***.
Basically I have a terminal in text edit mode. When the `RETURN` key is pressed, it just gets me a newline.

Any help regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your prompt might have gotten wiped out. Try this command:

```
setenv PROMPT '%m%# '
```

If that shows you a new prompt, consider customizing it and placing that command in your .tcshrc file. Here's a reference http://www.nparikh.org/unix/prompt.php

Comment: I have a problem that does not exactly relate to prompt. I have shell in a non-working state. And I do not use .tcshrc anyway. I set prompt in csh.cshrc. I made a small change in a question, just in case.